# Hibernate + Spring in a multi-threaded application

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, hibernate

The idea is to build a multi-threaded application with each thread connecting to a respective database (separate port numbers). Each thread would carry a process (let's say there are A, B, C and D) and there can be more than one thread instance of each process (eg. 2x A, 1x B, 0x C and 3x D) running concurrently.

My main two concerns are:

1. How to substitute `SessionFactory's` url property database ports during runtime?
2. How to restrict Hibernate's `Session` from accessing other thread's `Configuration`?

Ad 1. I found this solution, which is neat:
https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/. However, this only works fine if the application is single-threaded. Otherwise, processes A and B might encounter a conflict while trying to access the database at the same time.

Ad 2. Not really sure how to tackle this one. Is Spring smart enough to figure out which `Configuration` (ultimately, which database url) object to fetch in order to use it with the correct `Thread`?

Comment: *However, this only works fine if the application is single-threaded* no. Why would it? Read the article: it gets the datasource lookup key from a **thread-bound** context. So each thread has its own lookup key.

Comment: you need to create different sessionFacotry entry in xml or annotation for different databases;

Comment: @JB Nizet so what you're saying is Spring will have no problem with wiring `SessionFactory` to a `Thread`, right? Or, should I still id the beans, each according to its thread?

Comment: The idea of this DataSource is that you still have a single SessionFactory. But based on which thread is using it, the Session that is bound to the thread uses the DataSource that is also bound to the thread. Of course, all databases are supposed to have the same schema. The idea is to have, for example, an application used by 4 different customers, each with their own database.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can create multiple sessionFactory with thier own dataSource.

and at run time you will send sessionFacotry Name for getting data from different databases.

like

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(<sessionFactoryName>)
Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
      //block of code to execute    
session.close
```